Collapse accordion on page load
Is there a way to make accordion collapse on page load?
Currently t-store__tabs__item_active loads first.
Using a website builder with no capability of editing html, but can use css, js or jquery.
Loads first
What needs to load first
Tried to simulate click on page load with:
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".t-store__tabs__item.t-store__tabs__item_active").trigger('click');
    },10);
});

Possibly it's due to a syntax error.
Thanks.
